# Where do I get AMPs in WildStar?

Tags: wildstar

I know I can buy some on the auction house and that they drop. But is that the only place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get AMPs from several different sources:

- Quest rewards
- Vendors (often requiring a certain reputation level)
- Random world drops (including Scavenged Supplies bags)
- Trading / Auction house

There are many class-specific guides on the web for where to find all the different ones, and there's a useful addon called [AMP Finder](http://www.curse.com/ws-addons/wildstar/220169-amppurchased).

Comment: The addon was great i really recommend it for anyone reading this after me! It tells you where to get the AMP you're interested in.